# How to spell "Spalding" so that it is pronounced with /ɑː/ and not /ɔː/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

English being my second language aside, I want to call my dog *Spalding* and I want it to be pronounced with [ɑː] not [ɔː]. How do I write down *Spalding* to be pronounced that way?  I would like to know the pronunciation for both British English and speaker of American English so that it's [ˈspɑːldɪŋ].

Comment: Because "a" and "o" both have numerous possible pronunciations, could you please clarify using [International Phonetic Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) exactly which sounds you mean here, and in both cases? If you spell it *Spalding*, people will be most apt to pronounce it [ˈspɔːldɪŋ].

Comment: @suməlic I would like the second one. The `ɑ` vowel I believe it is.

Comment: @tchrist My thoughts exactly. I would like to avoid that and *enforce* `ɑ`. And I would also like the g to exist at the end.

Comment: You cannot get a *g* on the end if it ends with *-ing*. You would have to omit the *n*. No one would ever pronounce it *spælding* nor *spowlding* if you spell it *spalding*, so you do not have to worry about those possibilities.

Comment: @tchrist I see.  I would like to know the pronunciation for both British English and speaker of American English so that it's: `[ˈspɑːldɪŋ]`.

Comment: On the internet, no one can tell how your dog pronounces his name.

Comment: I'll just note that "Spalding" is the brand name for a major US purveyor of sporting equipment.  (Used to be the company name as well, but, as is usual these days, the company was bought out.)  The pronunciation of that name (in the US, at least) is about a consistent as any word pronunciation can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that speakers would normally pronounce "Spalding" as /ˈspɔːldɪŋ/.

If you want people to say /ˈspɑːldɪŋ/, the simplest option is to use "ah." By default, most English speakers pronounce this as /ɑː/. For example, consider the name "[Dahl](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dahl)," which Collins Dictionary transcribes as /dɑːl/. So, "Spahlding." (English spelling is often irregular, however, so even using "ah" will not guarantee the correct pronunciation. There are some words spelled with "ah" that are pronounced in other ways, such as "[mahlstick](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mahlstick)," which as Collins indicates may be pronounced /ˈmɔlˌstɪk/.)

Most British English speakers are non-rhotic (they don't pronounce "r" when it's at the end of a syllable). For non-rhotic speakers, a more common way of spelling /ɑː/ is as "ar." A non-rhotic British English speaker would naturally pronounce "Sparlding" as /ˈspɑːldɪŋ/.